# Angular 2 Rc.1 router not loading "/' component

Tags: angularjs, angular, router

I am attempting to use the new router from the rc.0 release. (Actually using rc.1) However I can't get the outlet to load the "Welcome" component.

Here is the app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from './common/header.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './common/welcome.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './common/footer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <header-component> </header-component> 
        <router-outlet> </router-outlet> 
    <footer-component> <footer-component> 
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HeaderComponent, WelcomeComponent, FooterComponent]
})

@Routes([
    {path: "/", component: WelcomeComponent}
]) 

export class AppComponent { 


}
```

Here is the main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

I'm not sure what I a missing, the path for / should work. index.html has the base ref set to "/" as well. I've been digging through the source to see what I a missing but not finding anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8409

> If you have routes setup without any router links and you don't inject the router, initial navigation does not occur.

So either you inject the `Router` or add `<a [routerLink]="...">` until this issue is fixed.

Comment: Please elaborate this line `So either you inject the Router` i doesn't where should I inject router

Comment: @RavinderPayal you inject it in the constructor. Seem my answer with an example.

Comment: Well now, that wasn't too obvious

Comment: Yup, the new router isn't yet fully baked.

Comment: I just noticed that this actually doesn't work for me, I'm injecting the router but it still doesn't do anything nor log anything. But It might be because I changed it to * like the WIP docs.

Comment: K got errors now: No provider for Router! Even though I'm bootstrapping ROUTER_PROVIDERS from @angular/router

Comment: Do you import **only** from `@angular/router` and **nothing** from `@angular/router-deprecated`?

Comment: It should be only /router i'll scan my project

Comment: I guess I'd need a Plunker to reproduce. I have no idea what could cause this error if `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are provided properly.

Comment: It's the only one now still the same problem.

Comment: Just to let you know I did find it now I also had a mention of angular2/router, which was mapped to deprecated by some typings in webpack-starter

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the constructor for AppComponent needed this:

```
export class AppComponent { 

    constructor(private _router:Router){

    }

}
```

Not sure why, if anyone has an answer for that?

Answer (score 2):

You still need to inject it using:

```
constructor(private _router:Router) { }
```

That's called *dependency injection*, also known as *constructor injection*. Your class depends on the Router. In the toplines of your code you declared where Angular could find the dependency with an `import` statement. You still need to instantiate (inject) the service before you can use it. That's what you declare in the constructor.

More info about Dependency Injection **[here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)**

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the `Router` never actually gets instantiated in your example. This happens because the `RouterOutlet` directive now doesn't depend on the `Router` service.

When the `Router` is instantiated, that's where it observes the initial URL and activates the initial routes.

The fix for the time being is to force the instantiation of the router by injecting the `Router` manually. Or - if you happen to have `routerLink`s in the template - it will happen automatically as `routerLink` *does* depend on `Router`.